# Django nested serializers not being applied to views

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm currently developing my django backend app defining some models for vehicles, but I've been unable to serialize the views for my purpose, I've attempted a couple changes but nothing works yet:

Models.py

```
class vehicles_brand(models.Model):
    pk_idbrand= models.AutoField(db_column='PK_IdBrand', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fk_idcountry= models.ForeignKey(locations_country, on_delete= models.CASCADE, db_column='FK_IdLocationCountry', related_name='Country')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None, null=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_photo_brand, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'vehicles_brand'
        verbose_name_plural = "Vehicle Brands"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class vehicles_model(models.Model):
    pk_idmodel = models.AutoField(db_column='PK_IdModel', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None)
    fk_idbrand= models.ForeignKey(vehicles_brand, on_delete= models.CASCADE, db_column='FK_IdVehicleBrand', related_name='Brand')
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'vehicles_model'
        verbose_name_plural = "Vehicle Models"

    # def __int__(self):
    #     return '{}'.format(self.pk_idmodel)

class vehicles_vehicle(models.Model):
    pk_idvehicle = models.AutoField(db_column='PK_IdVehicle', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fk_idmodel= models.ForeignKey(vehicles_model, on_delete= models.CASCADE, db_column='FK_IdVehicleModel', related_name="vehicle_model")
    fk_idbrand= models.ForeignKey(vehicles_brand, on_delete= models.CASCADE, db_column='FK_IdVehicleBrand', related_name="vehicle_brand")
    fk_idlocation= models.ForeignKey(locations_city, on_delete= models.CASCADE, 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'vehicles_vehicle'
        verbose_name_plural = "Vehicles"


    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.pk_idvehicle
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from vehicles.models import vehicles_vehicle, vehicles_model, vehicles_brand

class brandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = vehicles_brand
        fields = ['name']   
        depth = 3

class modelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = vehicles_model
        fields = ['name', 'body', 'cilinder_capacity', 'traction', 'traction_measure', 'fuel_consumption', 'fuel_consumption_measure', 'extras']   
        depth = 3

class vehicleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   

    fk_idbrand = brandSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    fk_idmodel = modelSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = vehicles_vehicle
        fields = ('pk_idvehicle', 'year', 'price', 'fk_idbrand', 'fk_idmodel')
        depth = 3
```

Views.py

```
from vehicles.serializers import vehicleSerializer,brandSerializer,modelSerializer
from vehicles.models import (vehicles_vehicle, vehicles_brand, vehicles_model)

@api_view(('GET',))
def get_all_brands(request):

    serializer_class = brandSerializer
    data = vehicles_brand.objects.all().values()

    return Response(data)

@api_view(('GET',))
def get_all_vehicles(request):

    serializer_class = vehicleSerializer
    data = vehicles_vehicle.objects.all().values()

    return Response(data)  

@api_view(('GET',))
def get_vehicle(request,id):

    serializer_class = vehicleSerializer
    data = vehicles_vehicle.objects.get(pk_idvehicle = id)

    return Response(data)
```

But I keep receiving the entire object with all the fields and key numbers for all my views, for example in brand:

```
 {
        "pk_idbrand": 1,
        "fk_idcountry_id": 1,
        "name": "Chevrolet",
        "logo": null
    },
    {
        "pk_idbrand": 2,
        "fk_idcountry_id": 1,
        "name": "Dodge",
        "logo": ""
    },
```

Thanks in advance for any hint or help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_all_brands(request):

    serializer_class = brandSerializer
    data = vehicles_brand.objects.all().values()

    return Response(data)
```

changes to be made:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
    def get_all_brands(request):
        data = vehicles_brand.objects.all().values()

        serializers = brandSerializer(data ,many=True)
        return Response(serializers.data)
```